# Convert Two Columns Into Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe like this:

[image]

And I wanted to split the 'Map Name' to Multiple Columns with the Value as the column name and 'Map Percentage' as the value of the column data.

**I tried using df.explode() and I get this:**

[image]

**What I want is something Like this which shows Map Name as Column Name and Map Percentage as it's value:**

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between "train" in the 1st row and the "train" in the 4th row?

Comment: @Back2Basics All of those are stats for different teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `concat`:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Map Name':[['Train', 'Vertigo', 'Nuke', 'Inferno'],
                              ['Inferno', 'Dust2', 'Vertigo']],
                   'Map Percentage':[['10%','20%','30%','40%'], ['5%','6%','7%']]})

(pd.concat([df['Map Name'].explode().reset_index(),
           df['Map Percentage'].explode()
                    .reset_index(drop=True)
                    .str.replace('%','').astype(float)],  # remove % and convert to float
          axis=1)
  .pivot_table(index='index', 
               columns='Map Name', 
               values='Map Percentage', 
               aggfunc='first',
               fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
Map Name  Dust2  Inferno  Nuke  Train  Vertigo
index                                         
0             0       40    30     10       20
1             6        5     0      0        7
```

Comment: This is working fine however I want to remove the index and Map Name from the dataframe. How Can I do that?

Comment: @AviThour `new_df.columns.name, new_df.index.name = None, None`

Comment: Just one last question, how should I remove the % from the values in the rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do it manually, with iterrows() to iterate over each of your rows, and then create a new dataframe with 2 columsn: `map` and `percentage` and then do a groupby map:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(["Map", "Percentage"]) 
for col in df.iterrows():
   for i in range(len(col["Map Name"])):
       new_df[col["Map Name"][i]] = col["Map Percentage"][i]]
# Group all rows matching the same map and get the average percentage for the group
new_df.groupby("Map").mean()
```

I'm not sure at all of the syntax to set the name of a dataframe and to append a new row, so I'll let you check that :), but for the logic it should work.

Ps: This will work correctly if you have a small dataframe (which I suppose you have, CounterStrike doesn't generate that much data :D), if not, maybe a lambda applied to every line would work better as it would allow staying in the dataframe world.

Comment: For some reason, i'm getting this error: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str